# Code is okay but form is not submitting data into the database, Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

Below is my code but when I click submit, the form refreshes and no data is sent into the database.

I have tried wire:model.lazy="email" and wire:model.defer="email" no change
have tried to run php artisan optimize:clear still the same
Have tried to run composer remove livewire/livewire && composer require livewire/livewire && php artisan optimize:clear no change
Kindly help me because the project is not showing any error

Class File

```
public $email;

public function storesubscribe()
{
    $subscriber = new Subscription();
    $subscriber->email = $this->email;
    $subscriber->save();
}
```

Blade

```
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7">
              <div class="subscribe-content-area text-center">
                  <h2 class="title text-white">Subscribe Our News Latters for Get Update </h2>
                  <form class="subscribe-form" wire:submit.prevent="storesubscribe">
                      <input wire:model="email" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                      <button type="submit" class="form-icon"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting `$this->email`? What class is it in? We need more context for the posted code.

Comment: This a home component, I extracted the part of mailing list subscription, and the class file is the homecomponent class file

Comment: is there a constructor that defines `$this->email` ?

Comment: I found out that my code has various <section></section> tags, when I removed the first section tag and its content, it worked. Now that I want to keep the tags, what can I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.